sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score is very slow
I need to measure accuracy of my model's prediction for binary classification (0 and 1 outputs). I am testing my model with many different values of threshold, and my testing dataset is quite big (50-100 million of examples), so I need a fast way to compute model's accuracy.
I was optimizing my code and noticed that the standard function for computing accuracy is ~50 times slower than the direct computation.
Minimal example:
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
import timeit
a=np.random.randint(0,2,1000000)
b=np.random.randint(0,2,1000000)
%timeit accuracy_score(a,b)
# 46.7 ms ± 390 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit (a==b).sum()/a.size
# 713 µs ± 7.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Am I missing something? It looks like accuracy_score is a standard way to measure accuracy. Why is it so slow? No C optimization under the hood?

There are two reasons why this happens. Part of the answer is that accuracy_score() is doing more validation to assure that the answer it's computing makes sense. Another part, however, is that some of this validation doesn't seem to have been implemented as efficiently as it could have been.
To explain why I think this, I'm going to show some profiling data. I obtained this data using line profiler, and the following Jupyter command:
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics._classification import _check_targets
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
%load_ext line_profiler
%lprun -f accuracy_score.__wrapped__ -f _check_targets -f type_of_target [accuracy_score(a,b) for i in range(10)]

Some notes about this:

The -f option controls which functions are getting traced. I tracing accuracy_score.__wrapped__ because accuracy_score() has a decorator. The other functions are things that accuracy_score() calls; we'll get into that.
[accuracy_score(a,b) for i in range(10)] is the code we're running.

Here's the result of this for accuracy_score:
Timer unit: 1e-09 s

Total time: 0.813048 s
File: /home/jupyter-njodell/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py
Function: accuracy_score at line 137

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   146                                           def accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, *, normalize=True, sample_weight=None):
   ...
   211                                           
   212                                               # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
   213        10  791633889.0    8e+07     97.4      y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   214        10     856305.0  85630.5      0.1      check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
   215        10      11260.0   1126.0      0.0      if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):
   216                                                   differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)
   217                                                   score = differing_labels == 0
   218                                               else:
   219        10   14279630.0    1e+06      1.8          score = y_true == y_pred
   220                                           
   221        10    6267160.0 626716.0      0.8      return _weighted_sum(score, sample_weight, normalize)

Notice that 97% of its time is spent inside _check_targets(). Let's trace that function:
Timer unit: 1e-09 s

Total time: 0.791422 s
File: /home/jupyter-njodell/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py
Function: _check_targets at line 58

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    58                                           def _check_targets(y_true, y_pred):
    59                                               """Check that y_true and y_pred belong to the same classification task.
    60                                           
    61                                               This converts multiclass or binary types to a common shape, and raises a
    62                                               ValueError for a mix of multilabel and multiclass targets, a mix of
    63                                               multilabel formats, for the presence of continuous-valued or multioutput
    64                                               targets, or for targets of different lengths.
    65                                           
    66                                               Column vectors are squeezed to 1d, while multilabel formats are returned
    67                                               as CSR sparse label indicators.
    ...
    84                                               """
    85        10     586514.0  58651.4      0.1      check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
    86        10  192463822.0    2e+07     24.3      type_true = type_of_target(y_true, input_name="y_true")
    87        10  172566835.0    2e+07     21.8      type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred, input_name="y_pred")
    88                                           
    89        10      11888.0   1188.8      0.0      y_type = {type_true, type_pred}
    90        10      15326.0   1532.6      0.0      if y_type == {"binary", "multiclass"}:
    91                                                   y_type = {"multiclass"}
    92                                           
    93        10      11207.0   1120.7      0.0      if len(y_type) > 1:
    94                                                   raise ValueError(
    95                                                       "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} and {1} targets".format(
    96                                                           type_true, type_pred
    97                                                       )
    98                                                   )
    99                                           
   100                                               # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed
   101        10      18352.0   1835.2      0.0      y_type = y_type.pop()
   102                                           
   103                                               # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
   104        10       7047.0    704.7      0.0      if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:
   105                                                   raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
   106                                           
   107        10       4171.0    417.1      0.0      if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:
   108        10      91096.0   9109.6      0.0          xp, _ = get_namespace(y_true, y_pred)
   109        10     930291.0  93029.1      0.1          y_true = column_or_1d(y_true)
   110        10     498877.0  49887.7      0.1          y_pred = column_or_1d(y_pred)
   111        10       4883.0    488.3      0.0          if y_type == "binary":
   112        10       2488.0    248.8      0.0              try:
   113        10  424147403.0    4e+07     53.6                  unique_values = _union1d(y_true, y_pred, xp)
   114                                                       except TypeError as e:
   115                                                           # We expect y_true and y_pred to be of the same data type.
   116                                                           # If `y_true` was provided to the classifier as strings,
   117                                                           # `y_pred` given by the classifier will also be encoded with
   118                                                           # strings. So we raise a meaningful error
   119                                                           raise TypeError(
   120                                                               "Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type. "
   121                                                               f"Got y_true={xp.unique(y_true)} and "
   122                                                               f"y_pred={xp.unique(y_pred)}. Make sure that the "
   123                                                               "predictions provided by the classifier coincides with "
   124                                                               "the true labels."
   125                                                           ) from e
   126        10      24858.0   2485.8      0.0              if unique_values.shape[0] > 2:
   127                                                           y_type = "multiclass"
   128                                           
   129        10      31701.0   3170.1      0.0      if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):
   130                                                   y_true = csr_matrix(y_true)
   131                                                   y_pred = csr_matrix(y_pred)
   132                                                   y_type = "multilabel-indicator"
   133                                           
   134        10       4790.0    479.0      0.0      return y_type, y_true, y_pred

There are two major uses of time in this function:

type_of_target() is called for both y_true and y_pred. This is 24.3% + 21.8% = 46.1% of time used.
_union1d() is called to get the number of distinct classes across both y_true and y_pred. This is 53.6% of time used.

What are both of these functions doing?
In type_of_target(), most time is spent on this line:
Total time: 0.364502 s
File: /home/jupyter-njodell/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py
Function: type_of_target at line 228

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   228                                           def type_of_target(y, input_name=""):
   ...
   [... snip many lines of code ...]
   ...
   395        20  361088394.0    2e+07     99.1      if xp.unique_values(y).shape[0] > 2 or (y.ndim == 2 and len(first_row) > 1):
   396                                                   # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
   397                                                   return "multiclass" + suffix

_union1d is taking the union of two NumPy arrays. It calls np.union1d, which is implemented like so:
def union1d(ar1, ar2):
    return unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2), axis=None))

In summary, for binary classification, accuracy_score spends 96% of its compute time computing one of three things:

np.unique(y_true)
np.unique(y_pred)
np.unique(np.concatenate([y_true, y_pred]))

However, the third thing can be computed from the first two.
Specifically, these three operations can be re-written as:
y_true_unique = np.unique(y_true)
y_pred_unique = np.unique(y_pred)
combined_unqiue = np.unique(np.concatenate([y_true_unique, y_pred_unique]))

In the case where the number of distinct classes is much smaller than the number of training examples (which I would think would apply to most machine learning problems) the second form would be about 50% faster, as np.concatenate([y_true_unique, y_pred_unique]) would be much smaller than np.concatenate([y_true, y_pred]).
Actually making this optimization and submitting a scikit-learn PR is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Cheers, thanks for the answer! I also use line_profiler, it is an awesome tool to dive deep into optimization problem.  I agree with you, the code is suboptimal, as the third np.unique() can be computed way more efficiently if number of unique labels is much smaller than the number of examples. Another optimization is to introduce the third parameter into the accuracy_score function - the number of unique values - and in this case avoid computing np.unique at all (of course, in this case one has to trust the user)

You can see from the accuracy_score source code that it's performing a lot more work than your comparison code snippet. It's also not directly written in C and only takes advantage of C-based optimizations indirectly via NumPy.
Operations you're not accounting for include:

Input type validation
Array length validation
Support for multiple array formats (NumPy, Python lists, etc.)
Support for multilabel classification


(a==b).sum()/a.size

Your comparison code (above) should always be much faster because it's less safe and less flexible. That's the tradeoff we make sometimes.

Thanks for the answer. From my experience, in the cases that you describe one usually observe a lot of performance advantage for small array sizes, while for large sizes there is almost no difference in performance (since input type/length validation are constant in time). In contrast, I see the difference in performance is almost the same when I increase the array size by a factor of 10. Something in your answer does not add up

@MikhailGenkin The overhead includes things with O(N) time complexity, like checking how many unique values the pred and true arrays contain. For example, code in type_of_target() is not just checking the type.
